# Swing window getting stuck when multiple files are passed

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am creating a code review app, which takes `.resource` format files and shares result. It works for 3-4 folders in a `.resource` format file, but when the folder size increases the window gets stuck.

```
public class CodeReviewWindow extends JDialog {

    private final JButton jbtOk = new JButton("Choose File");
    private final JButton jbtCancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    private final JLabel jlblStatus = new JLabel(" ");

    public CodeReviewWindow() {
        this(null, true);
    }

    public CodeReviewWindow(final JFrame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.add(jbtOk);
        p2.add(jbtCancel);

        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p5.add(p2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p5.add(jlblStatus, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        jlblStatus.setForeground(Color.RED);
        jlblStatus.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(p5, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });


        jbtOk.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

                int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
                Map<String, List<RuleViolation>> mapOfRuleViolation = new HashMap<>();
                BufferedInputStream bis = null;
                if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                    if (selectedFile.getName().endsWith(".resource")) {
                        try {
                            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

                            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
                            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                                ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                                File file = new File(entry.getName());
                                String name = file.getName();
                                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                                    continue;
                                } else {
                                    if (name.endsWith(".js")) {
                                        bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
                                        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                                        InputStream ruleSetsInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("xml/javascript.xml");
                                        File ruleSet = PmdReviewService.stream2file(ruleSetsInputStream, "javascript", ".xml");
                                        PMDConfiguration pmdConfiguration = new PMDConfiguration();
                                        pmdConfiguration.setReportFormat("text");
                                        pmdConfiguration.setRuleSets(ruleSet.getPath());
                                        pmdConfiguration.setThreads(4);
                                        SourceCodeProcessor sourceCodeProcessor = new SourceCodeProcessor(pmdConfiguration);
                                        RuleSetFactory ruleSetFactory = RulesetsFactoryUtils.getRulesetFactory(pmdConfiguration, new ResourceLoader());
                                        RuleSets ruleSets = RulesetsFactoryUtils.getRuleSetsWithBenchmark(pmdConfiguration.getRuleSets(), ruleSetFactory);

                                        PmdReviewService pmdReviewService = new PmdReviewService(sourceCodeProcessor, ruleSets);
                                        List<RuleViolation> review = pmdReviewService.review(bis, file);
                                        mapOfRuleViolation.put(file.getName(), review);

                                        Document document = new Document();
                                        try {
                                            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(name.replace(".js", "") + ".pdf"));
                                            document.open();
                                            document.add(new Paragraph("Code Review For " + name + " on " + new Date()));

                                            //ZapfDingbatsList List Example
                                            ZapfDingbatsList zapfDingbatsList = new ZapfDingbatsList(43, 30);
                                            for (RuleViolation ruleViolation : review) {
                                                zapfDingbatsList.add(new ListItem("Begin Line : " + ruleViolation.getBeginColumn() +
                                                        "\nIssue : " + ruleViolation.getDescription()));
                                            }

                                            document.add(zapfDingbatsList);
                                            document.close();
                                            writer.close();
                                            bis.close();
                                        } catch (DocumentException e1) {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                                            e1.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            zipFile.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            System.err.println(ex);
                        } finally {
                            setVisible(false);
                            parent.dispose();
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        });
        jbtCancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setVisible(false);
                parent.dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}


public class StaticCodeAnalysis extends JFrame {


    private CodeReviewWindow passDialog;

    public StaticCodeAnalysis() {
        passDialog = new CodeReviewWindow(this, true);
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                passDialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticCodeAnalysis staticCodeAnalysis = new StaticCodeAnalysis();

    }

}
```

Tried Using SwingWorker, now the application does not get stuck, but it never returns anything if more than 7 files are available in the folder.

```
SwingWorker swingWorker = new SwingWorker() {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Random random = new Random();
        int progress = 0;
        setProgress(0);
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            File file = new File(entry.getName());
            String name = file.getName();
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                continue;
            } else {
                // Same logic
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(zipFile.getInputStream(entry));
                    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                    InputStream ruleSetsInputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("xml/javascript.xml");
                    File ruleSet = PmdReviewService.stream2file(ruleSetsInputStream, "javascript", ".xml");
                    PMDConfiguration pmdConfiguration = new PMDConfiguration();
                    pmdConfiguration.setReportFormat("text");
                    pmdConfiguration.setRuleSets(ruleSet.getPath());
                    pmdConfiguration.setThreads(4);
                    SourceCodeProcessor sourceCodeProcessor = new SourceCodeProcessor(pmdConfiguration);
                    RuleSetFactory ruleSetFactory = RulesetsFactoryUtils.getRulesetFactory(pmdConfiguration, new ResourceLoader());
                    RuleSets ruleSets = RulesetsFactoryUtils.getRuleSetsWithBenchmark(pmdConfiguration.getRuleSets(), ruleSetFactory);

                    PmdReviewService pmdReviewService = new PmdReviewService(sourceCodeProcessor, ruleSets);
                    // Make random progress.
                    progress += random.nextInt(10);
                    setProgress(Math.min(progress, 100));
                    List<RuleViolation> review = pmdReviewService.review(bis, file);
                    mapOfRuleViolation.put(file.getName(), review);

                    Document document = new Document();
                    try {
                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(name.replace(".js", "") + ".pdf"));
                        document.open();
                        document.add(new Paragraph("Code Review For " + name + " on " + new Date()));

                        //ZapfDingbatsList List Example
                        ZapfDingbatsList zapfDingbatsList = new ZapfDingbatsList(43, 30);
                        for (RuleViolation ruleViolation : review) {
                            zapfDingbatsList.add(new ListItem("Begin Line : " + ruleViolation.getBeginColumn() +
                                    "\nIssue : " + ruleViolation.getDescription()));
                        }

                        document.add(zapfDingbatsList);
                        document.close();
                        writer.close();
                        bis.close();
                    } catch (DocumentException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            zipFile.close();
            setProgress(100);
            setVisible(false);
            parent.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        super.done();
    }
};

swingWorker.execute();
```

Comment: Seems like the error happens in some of your code that I cannot replicate. I see your application is processing those files in multiple threads (judging from the line pmdConfiguration.setThreads(4)). Have you checked if there are any exceptions occurring in those threads (like an OutOfMemory)? 
Also note that you should never do any major processing in the action listener itself, as this blocks the whole UI. Just calling new Thread(){your processing}.start() would also do, I personally never use SwingWorker.

Comment: There are no exceptions, if I leave the window open and let the program run, it will complete in 30-40 minutes.

Comment: Then maybe that's just how long it will take? If you always do the processing in separate threads then Swing should not have any issues. You can use a JProgressBar to always update on the progress.
Maybe it would help if you stated exactly what you expect vs. what is happening now and a code snipped with that issue that I could run too.

Comment: Rather than using setprogress to display info have u tried using publish () method and then overriding process() method in the worker thread? and maybe there u could print out or display what u need